# ! Package calc Error: `\let ' invalid at this point

Tags: errors

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{portuges}
\setotherlanguages{english}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\def\UrlBreaks{\do-\do\/}
\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym,amsthm,amsfonts,color,fancyhdr}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{5pt}


\setlist[enumerate]{noitemsep, topsep=10pt, partopsep=20pt}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label*=\enspace \arabic*.,before=\normalfont\mdseries,after=\normalfont,leftmargin=1.3em\large}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label*=\arabic*.,before=\normalfont\upshape\normalsize,after=\normalfont}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label*=\arabic*.,before=\normalfont\upshape,after=\normalfont}
\setlist[enumerate,4]{label*=\arabic*.,before=\normalfont\upshape,after=\normalfont}



%\makeindex

%\author{Luís Mendes}
\title{Informação }

\begin{document}


\iffalse
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\textsc{}
\\
\vspace{1cm}
\textsc{}
\\
\vspace{5cm}

\maketitle

\vspace{2cm}

1

{\large \emph{}}
\\
\vspace{5cm}

\begin{tabular}{l p{0.5\linewidth}}
Lu\\
()\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}


\end{titlepage}
\fi
% capa interior com menção dos orientadores
\thispagestyle{empty}



\newpage

\selectlanguage{portuges}
Proc
J

\vspace{1.5cm}

À Ex.\\
Ao Ex

\vspace{2cm}

Vila

\vspace{3.5cm}

E


\begin{enumerate}
\item {Quanto}

\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

What's wrong with this minimal example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your minimal example was not very minimal, removing packages unrelated to the problem a more specific example is

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}


\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc}

\setlist[enumerate]{noitemsep, topsep=10pt, partopsep=20pt}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label*=\enspace \arabic*.,before=\normalfont\mdseries,after=\normalfont,leftmargin=1.3em\large}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item {Quanto}

\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

The  setting `leftmargin=1.3em\large` is in error, `leftmargin` has to take a length value, without the `calc` package being loaded the error is not trapped and it accidentally runs to completion, but with the `calc` package (from `pdfpages`) you get an error. In either case the spurious `\large` should be removed.